# Retrieving saved value in onResume in android api 26

Tags: android, singleton, android-8.0-oreo

I am having an issue with saving and retrieving values in singleton class only in android oreo.I have an activity which has 4 fragments.1st fragment shows productlist.Whenever user selects that product,I am saving that product in singleton class variable.Now when I try to retrieve this value in second fragment.It shows null pointer exception.
I am storing value in onStop() and retrieving value in onResume().
Below is the onStop Method of fragmentProduct where I am storing order in orderList

**FragmentProduct**

```
 public void onStop()
    {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d("stop","called");
        globalProvider.shangpingListDefault.clear();
        if(MiTems!=null) {
            for(int i=0;i<MiTems.size();i++){
                for(int a=0;a<MiTems.get(i).size();a++){
                    globalProvider.shangpingListDefault.add(MiTems.get(i).get(a));
                }
            }

        }

        List<OrderSubmit> orderList=new ArrayList<OrderSubmit>();
        this.shangPingList=globalProvider.shangpingList;
        List<Contract> contractList=globalProvider.contractListToCart;
        for (int i = 0; i < globalProvider.contractListToCart.size(); i++) {
            //globalProvider.orders.add(new OrderSubmit());
            OrderSubmit order = new OrderSubmit();
            order.products = new ArrayList<Product>();
            //Contract contract=globalProvider.contractListToCart.get(i);
            for (int a = 0; a < globalProvider.shangpingList.size(); a++) {
                Product product = globalProvider.shangpingList.get(a);
                if (globalProvider.contractListToCart.get(i)._supplier.equals(product.get_supplier())) {
                    order.products.add(product);
                }
            }
            orderList.add(order);
            Log.d("orderlist","orderadded");
        }
```

Below is the OnResumeMethod of FragmentCart where I am retrieving order in onResume

**FragmentCart**

```
public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();

        orders=globalProvider.orders;
        Log.d("checksizeorder",globalProvider.orders.size()+"");

        setSelect();

    }
```

In MainActivity,whenever tab is selected I am replacing these fragment:
**MainActivity**

```
public void setSelect(int i){
        FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction=fm.beginTransaction();
        //hide(transaction);
        switch(i){
            case 0:
                if(globalProvider.singal==0){
                    return;
                }
                globalProvider.singal=0;
                FragmentContract fragment_contract = new FragmentContract();
                transaction.replace(R.id.main, fragment_contract);
                shangping_Img.setImageResource(R.drawable.shangping_pressed);
                cart_Img.setImageResource(R.drawable.cart);
                dingdan_Img.setImageResource(R.drawable.dingdan);
                wode_Img.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_info);
                one.setTextColor(0xffee2400);
                two.setTextColor(0xff666666);
                three.setTextColor(0xff666666);
                four.setTextColor(0xff666666);
                break;
            case 1:
                if(globalProvider.singal==1){
                    return;
                }
                globalProvider.singal=1;
                FragmentCart cart_fragment=new FragmentCart();
                transaction.replace(R.id.main, cart_fragment);
                shangping_Img.setImageResource(R.drawable.shangping);
                cart_Img.setImageResource(R.drawable.cart_pressed);
                dingdan_Img.setImageResource(R.drawable.dingdan);
                wode_Img.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_info);
                one.setTextColor(0xff666666);
                two.setTextColor(0xffee2400);
                three.setTextColor(0xff666666);
                four.setTextColor(0xff666666);
                break;
```

Comment: It would help if you post some code. Quick note, onStop for fragment wont be called if you are showing another fragment unless you are actually destroying it. You may consider saving the value when the fragment becomes invisible.

Comment: @MoGa :Updated.Please See,My onStop Method does get called whenever I moved to the other fragment,as I checked with the logger.

Comment: onPause is the reciprocal of onResume - in other words you can get to onResume without onStop.

Comment: @Andy I have tried saving value in onPause too.It didnt work

Comment: What I realised is,onResume method of new fragment is called before onStop

Comment: Even onPause is called before onResume of new fragment.Please help!

Answer (score 0):

There is some problem with Fragment in oreo version.I created a separate app to check what lifecycle functions are called when we replace one fragment with other..Here is the log:

```
MainActivity onCreate ->
FragmentA oncreate ->
FragmentA oncreateView ->
MainActivity onStart ->
FragmentA onStart ->
MainActivity onResume ->
FragmentA onResume ->
Button Pressed;that replace fragment A with Fragment B
FragmentB oncreate ->
FragmentB onCreateVew ->
FragmentB onStart ->
FragmentB onResume ->
FragmentA onPause ->
FragmentA onStop ->
FragmentA onDestroy ->
```

I was importing import android.app.Fragment.It worked when I  replaced it with android.support.v4.app.Fragment .